# How to use distributed training in tensorflow to merge states of a custom metric

Tags: gpu, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am trying to use the `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy` in tensorflow (v2.9) to write my code to run across 4 GPUs.

My problem is that my I am unable to figure out how to aggregate the computed metrics across GPUs.

I am using `Model.compile` and `Model.fit` from keras. My code is able to run on multiple GPUs. Therefore, as mentioned in the documentation ([Loss reduction and scaling is done automatically in Keras Model.compile and Model.fit](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/custom_training#define_the_metrics_to_track_loss_and_accuracy)), I am just defining my model.compile call inside the strategy scope, example,

```
with strategy.scope():
    model = MY_ML_MODEL_CLASS()
    loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(reduction = tf.keras.losses.Rediuction.SUM)
    metric = My_CUSTOM_METRIC()
    model.compile(
                  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = lr),
                  loss = loss,
                  metrics = metric)
```

Now, I am using a [custom metric](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Metric) defined using functional APIs.

```
class MY_CUSTOM_METRIC(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):

  def __init__(self, name='MY_CUSTOM_METRIC', **kwargs):
    super().__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
    self.my_custom_metric = self.add_weight(name='mcm', initializer='zeros')
    self.precision = tf.keras.metrics.Precision()
    self.Recall = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()

  def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.bool)
    y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, tf.bool)

    custom_operation = self.precision(y_true,y_pred) <op> self.recall(y_true,y_pred) // <op> is some operation that i am doing, but the range of custom operation is still [0,1].
   
    self.my_custom_metric.assign(custom_operation)

  def result(self):
    return self.my_custom_metric

  def reset_state(self):
     self.precision.reset_state()
     self.recall.reset_state()
     self.my_custom_metric.reset_state()
```

When I run using this custom metric on CPU the value of my metrics remain between 0 and 1 as they should be. But, running this on 4 GPUs, the custom metric's value exceeds 1. I am guessing it's something to do with how results of metrics from different GPUs are aggregated. HOw do I fix this aggregation when running on GPUs?

I tried using the `merge_state`. But, there is not a lot of tensorflow documentation or other stack overflow answers that could help. Anyways, I tried the followin addition of `merge_state` to the custom metri. But, this didn't have any effect and I still am getting the metric's value out of range [0, 1].

```
class MY_CUSTOM_METRIC(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):

  def __init__(self, name='MY_CUSTOM_METRIC', **kwargs):
    super().__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
    self.my_custom_metric = self.add_weight(name='mcm', initializer='zeros')
    self.precision = tf.keras.metrics.Precision()
    self.Recall = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()

  def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.bool)
    y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, tf.bool)

    custom_operation = self.precision(y_true,y_pred) <op> self.recall(y_true,y_pred) // <op> is some operation that i am doing, but the range of custom operation is still [0,1].
   
    self.my_custom_metric.assign(custom_operation)

  def merge_state(self, states):
      for state in states:
          self.my_custom_metric.append(state)
      self.my_custom_metric = tf.reduce_mean(self.my_custom_metric)

  def result(self):
    return self.my_custom_metric

  def reset_state(self):
     self.precision.reset_state()
     self.recall.reset_state()
     self.my_custom_metric.reset_state()
```

I do not want to write custom training loop and want to use the model.fit and model.compile. I want to just change the custom metric function.